# Menu toggle CSS only doesn't work when it is inside the element

Tags: html, css

Edit:

I removed my question. I believe that CSS only isn't a really functional and decent way to code a sliding nav. Therefore I created it with a littlebit jQuery instead.

Working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#toggle-nav").click(function() {
    $(".main-nav").toggleClass("nav-trans");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.main-nav {
  position: fixed;
  background: #000;
  padding-left: 2em;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}
.main-nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -1em;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 0;
}
.main-nav li {
  padding: 1em;
}
#toggle-nav {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 30em;
  position: absolute;
  right: -1.7em;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
}
.nav-trans {
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <div id="toggle-nav"></div>
    <ul>
      <li>pagina1</li>
      <li>pagina2</li>
      <li>pagina3</li>
      <li>pagina4</li>
      <li>pagina5</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Maybe this could help someone in the future.

Comment: You have both code, so its easy to you to check that code determine what's going wrong?

Comment: check your `li` tage in the `ul` you have closing the `</h1>' instead of the `li` tag.

Comment: If it was easy for me, I wouldn't ask :P. I just don't know why it's going wrong.

Comment: Ah, stupid mistake :P That doesn't  resolve my problem though :(

Comment: on your second CSS code `#toggle-nav` id you have the extra `left: 9em;` remove it check it may be worked: I also put your both code in `JSFiddle` and it worked here. https://jsfiddle.net/01c77wes/  https://jsfiddle.net/j5Lr0vy0/

Comment: Check this and tell me it worked for you or not???

Comment: Just doesn't when I put this checkbox inside the nav element. Also when I remove the left: 9em;

Comment: You checked live demo, I posted the link. Check it

Comment: Checked both of them. But you didn't put the checkbox element inside the nav like I did.

Comment: okay sorry, Now I get your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with the input inside the nav than you should apply the html like this:

```
<nav>
    <input id="toggle-nav" type="checkbox">
    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li>pagina1</li>
        <li>pagina2</li>
          <li>pagina3</li>
          <li>pagina4</li>
          <li>pagina5</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Thanks. After all I don't think it's a decent way to code the menu with CSS only. I will post my working nav with jquery

Comment: But It would not worked? You tried yourself ? That's the problem asked in the question.